# Read and Write structure to a binary file

Tags: c, file

I am trying to read and write structure to a binary file. This is what I have done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma pack (1)
typedef struct employee
{
    char name[20];
    char empNo[10];
    int age;
    double salary;
}employee;

int main()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    long lSize;
    char * buffer;
    size_t result;
    employee e1 = {"Testing", "8208", 21, 1000.500};
    employee e2;

    pFile = fopen("myfile.bin" , "w+");
    fwrite(&e1, sizeof(e1), 1, pFile);
    buffer =(char*) calloc(1, sizeof(e1));
    if(buffer == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Memory error",stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    rewind(pFile);
    // I know, I can read it to e2. But wanted to try to read to buffer.
    result = fread(buffer,sizeof(e2),1,pFile); 

    if(result != 1) 
    {
        fputs("Reading error",stderr); 
        exit(1);
    }
    sscanf(buffer,"%s %s %d %lf",e2.name,e2.empNo,&e2.age,&e2.salary);
    printf("%s %s %d %lf",e2.name,e2.empNo,e2.age,e2.salary);// Printing some garbage.
    fclose(pFile);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I know, that I can read directly to `e2` variable using `fread`. But thought of trying to read it to `buffer` and then from the `buffer` read to `e2`. But not working. Dont know what mistake I am doing. I thought, it might be because of padding. So added `#pragma pack`. But no use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: open as `rw+` so can be read from. Also what output/behaviour do you see - try set some breakpoints in your debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have to use this

```
sscanf(buffer,"%s %s %d %lf",e2.name,e2.empNo,&e2.age,&e2.salary);
```

when you are using a struct as when you wrote to the file you wrote the struct into the file, therefore when reading back you should read the entire struct no parsing is required as it will read and assign everything accordingly.Use memcpy as suggested

```
memcpy(&e2,buffer,sizeof(e2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your `sscanf()`. Use `memcpy()` instead of `sscanf()` like,

```
memcpy((char *)&e2,buffer,sizeof(e2));
```

It is working fine for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma pack (1)
typedef struct employee
{
    char name[20];
    char empNo[10];
    int age;
    double salary;
}employee;

int main()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    long lSize;
    char * buffer;
    size_t result;
    employee e1 = {"Testing", "8208", 21, 1000.500};
    employee e2;

    pFile = fopen("myfile.bin" , "w+");
    fwrite(&e1, sizeof(e1), 1, pFile);
    buffer =(char*) calloc(1, sizeof(e1));
    if(buffer == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Memory error",stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    rewind(pFile);
    // I know, I can read it to e2. But wanted to try to read to buffer.
    result = fread(buffer,sizeof(e2),1,pFile);

    if(result != 1)
    {
        fputs("Reading error",stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    memcpy((char *)&e2,buffer,sizeof(e2));
//    sscanf(buffer,"%s %s %d %lf",e2.name,e2.empNo,&e2.age,&e2.salary);
    printf("%s %s %d %lf",e2.name,e2.empNo,e2.age,e2.salary);// Printing some garbage.
    fclose(pFile);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
} 

                                                                                                                                                          1,1           Top
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `sscanf` function.

```
7.21.6.7  The sscanf function is equivalent to fscanf, except that input is 
obtained from a string (specified by the argument s) rather than from a stream.
```

Standard says that, it will be read from string.

In your case, the  `char name[20];` is 20 bytes long and you are assigning `"Testing"` to it. What happened to remaining bytes? These remaining bytes are the garbage that you are getting.
Also you are trying to read `integer` (which is 4 bytes in your case) and a `double` (which is 8 bytes) which are there as is in the `buffer` and they are not string.

What I feel is you are invoking undefined behavior here...